# Regular expressions converting into a diagram

Tags: regex, diagram

Is there any software to convert a regular expression into a diagram to show the finite state machine will work. I find it helpful to have things pictorial to aid in bug fixing and ensuring that the regular expression is correct.

Comment: You mean regular expressions containing look-around assertions as well?

Comment: Just simple ones would be a help without the look-around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) - IMHO it's best tool for regexp creation, validation, advanced visualisation and debugging. Also  it has the unique ability to emulate the features and limitations of all the popular regular expression flavors, like PCRE, Perl, JavaScript, Java and etc.

Answer (score 13):

I really like http://www.regexper.com/ which looks like it uses [Parcon](http://blog.parcon.opengroove.org/2011/07/generating-syntax-diagrams-from-parcon.html).

Example ([live link](http://www.regexper.com/#%28hello|good%28bye%29%3F%29%5Cs[Ww]orld%5C.%3F)):

[image: Regexp visualization example]

Comment: That is rather good. Give it a few more tries.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using eclipse... http://crotonresearch.com/graphrex/

Answer (score 2):

I ran a google search for `"regex visualization" graphvis`, and I found this:

http://osteele.com/archives/2006/02/reanimator

The tool is web based. I was actually hoping that I might be able to find a command line tool, because that would be easier to script. Nonetheless, the implementation seems to be well documented, and might serve as a starting point for other tools.

Comment: Above link is broken!

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a good online tool for this at http://www.strfriend.com. Unfortunately, it appears to be currently unavailable.

[image: Strfriend screenshot]